# Generating a dynamic graph on USA map

Tags: visualisation

I want to reproduce the dynamic US map showing the obesity percentage across the years 1984-2009 as shown in the CDC website http://www.cdc.gov/obesity/data/trends.html

I am looking for tools and code to get started on this.

EDIT 1 (Apr 22 2011)

I was able to gather the data (1994-2009) and I have uploaded it to Google docs in [csv format](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AhHsfeF-a4mRdEp5Z0dXQ3haT2FROEMwNVpFN3RDZkE&hl=en#gid=0).

Using `R` and `googleVis` I was able to generate a map for a single year (say 1994) using `gvisGeoMap`. But I want to create a map which will motion through years 1994 to 2009. I am not sure how to add the *motion* ability to `gvisGeoMap`. Do I need to look at some other tool?

Comment: Another option is here: http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/

Answer (score 6):

I would look at the google visualization API: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html

If you are familiar and comfortable with R, there is an R interface that may simplify things: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the above Google/R route if that is what you are comfortable with.

Alternatively Polymaps has some great looking data visualisations http://polymaps.org/

Finally [here](http://makingmaps.net/2007/07/31/animated-maps-in-google-earth/) is a tutorial for creating animated maps in Google Earth